# Retrieving JSON depending on user input

Tags: javascript, json, loops, fetch

I'm trying to pull data from a JSON file depending on the user input that has come from various checkboxes. An example of my JSON file is below;

```
{
        "factor": 1,
        "pathway": 2,
        "title": "Lorem impsum",
},
{
        "factor": 3,
        "pathway": 2,
        "title": "Lorem impsum",
},
{
        "factor": 4,
        "pathway": 2,
        "title": "Lorem impsum",
},
```

I first loop through the values of the checkboxes to get an array for each category of user input so i'll end up with two arrays that look something like this.

```
factorArray = [1,3,4]
pathwayArray = [2]
```

What would be the best way to compare these arrays during the fetch request, and pull relevant JSON where the two values relate? So for this example all three of the JSON objects would be returned.

My fetch code currently looks like this:

```
function getFactors(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var checkboxesPath = document.querySelectorAll('#pathway:checked')
    var pathwayArray = [];
    // Retrieve user input from checkboxes
    for (var i = 0; i< checkboxesPath.length; i++) {
        pathwayArray.push(checkboxesPath[i].value)
    } 
    var checkboxesFactor = document.querySelectorAll('#factors:checked')
    var factorsArray = [];

    for (var i = 0; i< checkboxesFactor.length; i++) {
        factorsArray.push(checkboxesFactor[i].value)
    } 
    
    fetch("pathway.json")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        let output = ``;
        var results = data.filter(obj => factorsArray.includes(obj.factor) && pathwayArray.includes(obj.pathway))
        console.log(results);
     })
    
}
```

I've tried looping through the arrays while in the map function but cannot get it to work for multiple values, in plain english I'm hoping to get something like this

```
where factorArray[i] == pathwayArray[i] {
    push relevant JSON to DOM
}
```

Comment: Too vague matey.

Comment: Do you mean filtering that JSON file in the javascript, or changing your backend to do it for you? Adding some more details to your question could help us help you

Comment: What is the shape of data?

Comment: Hey - apologies I've added a bit more detail. 

I'm hoping to filter the JSON file in the javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't selectively fetch some objects from your JSON array since it's a simple file database. If you really need this, you'll have to use more complex database tools (consider google cloud firestore).

But you can filter the received data after the entire json content has been fetched. Like so:

```js
fetch("pathway.json")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        let output = ``;
        var results = data.filter(obj => factorArray.includes(obj.factor) && factorArray.includes(obj.pathway))
     })
```

Comment: This is perfect thanks, I have it working in isolation however when I use this within a function (that runs once a user has submitted their data which gives the arrays im comparing against their values) the results variable is returning empty - am I missing something obvious here? Thanks again.

Comment: It'll be nice if I can see some more data and code regarding this new issue

Comment: I've added the whole function on to the original post Jay, thanks. That getFactors function runs once the user has submitted the selection of checkboxes, I don't see it as an issue with how I've handled that data as they both end up as two seperate arrays. I think I'm missing something with the filter code

Comment: You should try logging the values of `factorsArray` and `pathwayArray` when you just before you send the request and let me know

Comment: They behave as expected and log as an array based on the values of the user selection

Comment: Let's continue this discussion in chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220027/retrieving-json-depending-on-user-input

Answer (score 0):

```
var factorArray = [1,3,4];
var pathwayArray = [2];

const exampleJsonArr = [
{
        "factor": 1,
        "pathway": 2,
        "title": "Lorem impsum",
},
{
        "factor": 3,
        "pathway": 2,
        "title": "Lorem impsum",
},
{
        "factor": 3,
        "pathway": 2,
        "title": "Lorem impsum",
},
{
        "factor": 343,
        "pathway": 52,
        "title": "Lorem impsum",
},
{
        "factor": 3,
        "pathway": 22,
        "title": "Lorem impsum",
},
{
        "factor": 31,
        "pathway": 2,
        "title": "Lorem impsum",
},
{
        "factor": 4,
        "pathway": 2,
        "title": "Lorem impsum",
}]

exampleJsonArr.filter(obj => {return pathwayArray.includes(obj.pathway) || factorArray.includes(obj.factor)})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Solution:

```
    var data = [{
        "factor": 1,
        "pathway": 2,
        "title": "Lorem impsum",
    },
    {
      "factor": 3,
      "pathway": 2,
      "title": "Lorem impsum",
    },
    {
      "factor": 4,
      "pathway": 2,
      "title": "Lorem impsum",
    },
    {
      "factor": 5,
      "pathway": 4,
      "title": "Lorem impsum",
    },
    {
      "factor": 6,
      "pathway": 5,
      "title": "Lorem impsum",
    }];
    
    var factorArray = [1,3,4]
    var pathwayArray = [2]
    
    var result = data.filter((item) => {
        return factorArray.includes(item.factor) && pathwayArray.includes(item.pathway);
    });
    
    console.log(result);
```